# Multiple Javascripts plugins slowing down the page, anyway to clean this up?

Tags: javascript, performance

well I'm new to JavaScript so I know that my work will look nasty but I have been looking for a solution for a week now, I tried to put some JavaScript in the Head tag and so but it didn't get any faster so I said if there is one I'll get it here :D here are the link to the project please have a look at it and if there is something to do about it I'll appreciate it thank you all! 
http://www.ayman.benhamida.com/metalexfinal/

Comment: for starters you are loading 2 different jQuery versions, you might want to consolidate using 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your site looks pretty nice! ;) However, I saw the following problems:

1. you have two javascript versions included. Kick one out!
2. Very important: You have several `.js` which are uncompressed. Use an online-compressor to minify them: [this one](http://www.refresh-sf.com/yui/) or [this one](http://fmarcia.info/jsmin/test.html) or just pick one, you like.
3. You have a lot of jquery-plugins. You can merge them together into one file.
4. Fix your 404-errors (css/bullets.png, css/loading.gif)
5. Place your scripts as far to the bottom of your page as possible. (best position would be before `</body>`). This speeds up the initial page-construction.
6. minify your css.
7. compress your images.

Answer (score 0):

- Use minfied Javascript.
- Use minfied CSS.
- Combine Javascript files.
- Combine CSS files.
- Compress your images more.
- You use 2 versions of jQuery ( http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js and http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js ).
- Split your page up into seprate pages, so you don't need to load things like http://www.ayman.benhamida.com/metalexfinal/images/map.png (which is 181.1kb in size) on the home page. Only load resources when they are needed, i.e. when someone wants to see the map!
- http://www.ayman.benhamida.com/metalexfinal/images/para_green.png is 235.2kb in size. Compress this more!!